# The 2-norm of diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis

Compute:

$$||A||_2$$

for a diagonal matrix

Is there any way to find the 2-norm here without talking or using the Eigenvalue (largest Eigenvalue )

Comment: The 2-norm of a matrix is *defined* in terms of the largest eigenvalue of the square of the matrix, and is very easy to find for diagonal matrices. Why would you need to do this without eigenvalues?

Comment: Because we didn't study the Eigenvalue yet and I have to find 2-norm of diagonal matrix... Can I find it in general without saying this the largest Eigenvalue? If not how can I prove it then?

Comment: Has your instructor given any materials in lecture related to properties of diagonal matrices or matrix two-norms?

Comment: $$||A||_2=\max \frac{|Ax|_2}{|x|_2}$$ which is very easy to determine for a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Paul Wow I am rusty. I forgot about that definition of norms. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$||A||_2=\max \frac{|Ax|_2}{|x|_2}$$